# If X and Y are metric spaces, f: X → Y is continuous and V ⊆ Y is connected, then $f^{−1}(V )$ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

It is a true or false question.

I was given the example that $f(x)  = x^2$ and $V = (0,\infty)$ proves that this is false but how do we actually prove this.

Obviously, it means we can not write $V$ as $A \cup B$ where $A,B$ are separated but I wasn't sure where to take if from there!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "actually prove this"?  Are you just trying to show thaat $V$ is connected (this is what your second sentence suggests)?  Please make your question clear.

Comment: Hi Erick, sorry its actually a true or false question. So the example I provided proves this is not true. Sorry about that

Comment: I disagree: "but how do you actually prove this" is not a true/false question at all.

Comment: I disagree: it most certainly is. In the edited version I fixed it. So "how do you actually price this" relates to the fact that the example $f(x) =x^2$ proves the question/statement is false. I want to prove that.

Comment: My point is that **your** question is not clear.  I don't mean the question you're working on (you already know that's false), I mean the question you're asking.  Notice that the answers so far have focused on proving that $f^{-1}(V)$ is disconnected, while you describe being stuck at "we cannot write $V$ as $A \cup B$", which suggests you are not sure why $V$ is connected.  It's helpful if you describe more about what you are stuck on, and that is certainly not a true/false question.

Comment: Examples: "I don't know what it means to prove $f$ is a counterexample", "I don't see why $f$ is continuous", "I don't know what $f^{-1}(V)$ means", "I don't know what it means for $f^{-1}(V)$ to be disconnected", "I don't see how to decompose $f^{-1}(V)$ into two open sets", "I don't know what it means for $V$ to be connected", "I don't how to show that V cannot be written as $A\cup B$ with $A,B$ disjoint open sets"... There's a lot of ground to cover in "how do you actually prove this": some of it is obvious to you and some is not.  So, what's your question?

Answer (score 3):

Note that 
$$
f^{(-1)}(V) = \Bbb{R}\setminus \{0 \};
$$
hence we can find two sets $A,B$ open in $f^{(-1)}(V)$ such that $A \cup B = f^{(-1)}(V)$ and $A \cap B = \varnothing$, namely $A := ]-\infty, 0[$ and $B := ]0, \infty[$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be two discs

$$
\mathsf{O}\;\;\; \mathsf{O}
$$

and let $Y$ be one disc

$$
\mathsf{O}
$$

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be the map which maps each of the two discs in $X$ to the disc $Y$ (via the identity map), and let $V$ be the whole of $Y$.  What is $f^{-1}(V)$?  Is it connected?

Comment: Well it's not actually the indentity map.

Comment: @zhw When I say 'via the identity map', I mean that the map is the identity on each copy of the disc.  Interpreting $X$ as $Y\sqcup Y$, a map $X\to Y$ is induced by a pair of maps $Y\to Y$; my map is induced by the pair $(\text{id}_Y,\text{id}_Y$.